# Excel 2007 Transpot - Merge with if statements

Tags: excel, excel-2007

I have to do a task in excel 2007 and I can't find a way !

I have this table:

```
        A       B         C           D
1    CODE    NUMBER    USERID      CHECKED
2    100     1501        317         OK
3    100     1502        318
4    100     1600        319
5    100     1601        319
6    101     1503        319
7    101     1504        317         OK 
8    101     1120        317
9    102     1505        325
10   102     1506        328
11   102     1807        319
12   102     1808        313         OK
13   102     2012        317
```

And going on... ( I have some more criteria but I think I can do it alone if I know the right function )

So my output is gonna be like that:

```
 |      F     |       G                     |         H
1| (IF A:A =) | (AND IF D:D <> OK) -        | (AND IF D:D <> OK) -    
 |            |    WITHOUT USERID           |    WITH USERID
2|   100      | 1502 - 1600 - 1601          | 1502(317) - 1600(319) - 1601 (319) --and keep going if have more
3|   101      | 1503 - 1120                 | 1503(319) - 1120(317) --and keep going if have more
4|   102      | 1505 - 1506 - 1807 - 2012   | 1505(325) - 1506(328) - 1807(319) - 2012(317) --and keep going if have more
```

In my table i have like 120 codes, 10 userid and every number is unique.

Comment: You have my sympathy - I am having to work in Excel 97/2003 compatibility mode at the moment. Will post something shortly.

Answer (score 0):

Below Array formula will work for your problem. Since `COL:D` criteria are identical in your input, I have arranged them as I wish; if it is the way opposite, you have to reverse it.

Write the formula to `E2`, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> and copy it down. The formula will have "{" and "}" characters at the beginning and at the end.

```
=IF(D2="OK",CONCAT(IF(A2=A:A, B:B&" - ","")),CONCAT(IF(A2=A:A, B:B&"("&C2&") - ","")))
```

You will have an excess "-" at the end of the strings; if it is a problem, you may remove them using the `LEFT` function giving the length parameter as `LEN()-1` of the string.

**EDIT:**

I have found a much neater solution which does not create "-" at the end. This is again an array formula (s/b entered by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>). The only possible problem is that `TEXTJOIN` is a kind of new formula which older Excel versions does not support.

```
=IF(D2="OK",TEXTJOIN(" - ",TRUE,IF($A$2:$A$13=A2,$B$2:$B$13,"")), TEXTJOIN(" - ",TRUE,IF($A$2:$A$13=A2,$B$2:$B$13 & "("& $C$2:$C$13&")","")))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Excel 2007, you can use things like SUMPRODUCT and IFERROR, but you can't use AGGREGATE and you certainly can't use TEXTJOIN.

So I think it's unlikely that there is a neat solution to this. I would do something like this:

You are going to need some helper columns unfortunately. In order to work out how many helper columns you would need you could use a formula like this (entered as an array formula) to find the maximum number of numbers per Code

```
=MAX(FREQUENCY(IF((D2:D100<>"OK")*(A2:A100<>""),A2:A100),A2:A100))
```

Then assuming you have a way of tabulating the unique Codes, you could use SMALL to pull out the different numbers per code which do not have OK against them, and (since the concatenate function available in Excel 2007 does not work with arrays) concatenate them with the previous result starting in H2:

```
=IFERROR(IF(G2="","",G2&" - ")&SMALL(IF(($D$2:$D$100<>"OK")*($A$2:$A$100=$F2),$B$2:$B$100),COLUMNS($A:A)),G2)
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

The UserID can be added starting in M2

```
=IFERROR(IF(L2="","",L2&" - ")&SMALL(IF(($D$2:$D$100<>"OK")*($A$2:$A$100=$F2),$B$2:$B$100),COLUMNS($A:A))
&" ("&VLOOKUP(SMALL(IF(($D$2:$D$100<>"OK")*($A$2:$A$100=$F2),$B$2:$B$100),COLUMNS($A:A)),$B$2:$C$100,2,FALSE)&")",L2)
```

[image]